# Can I use TwitterKit to access Twitter's Streaming APIs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I've set up TwitterKit in my Xcode project. I'm using Objective C, and I can successfully access Tweets by ID, and query the REST API. However I want to use the Streaming API and the documentation doesn't make it clear if I can do Streaming or not, say for tweets containing the word "space".

Using the code below I never get get a response object. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated:

```
NSString *statusesShowEndpoint = @"https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/sample.json";
NSDictionary *params = @{};
NSError *clientError;
NSURLRequest *request = [[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
                     URLRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                     URL:statusesShowEndpoint
                     parameters:params
                     error:&clientError];

if (request) {
[[[Twitter sharedInstance] APIClient]
 sendTwitterRequest:request
 completion:^(NSURLResponse *response,
              NSData *data,
              NSError *connectionError) {

     NSLog(@"response0 %@", response);

     if (data) {
         // handle the response data e.g.
         NSError *jsonError;
         NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                               JSONObjectWithData:data
                               options:0
                               error:&jsonError];

         NSLog(@"json %@", json);
         NSLog(@"response1 %@", response);

     }
     else {
         NSLog(@"Error1: %@", connectionError);
         NSLog(@"response2 %@", response);

     }
 }];
}
 else {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", clientError);

}
```